# Why do I get this exception? {An item with the same key has already been added."})

Tags: linq-to-entities

Aknittel
NewSellerID is the result of a lookup on tblSellers. These tables (tblSellerListings and tblSellers) are not "officially" joined with a foreign key relationship, either in the model or in the database, but I want some referential integrity maintained for the future. So my issue remains. Why do I get the exception ({"An item with the same key has already been added."}) with this code, if I don't begin each iteration of the foreach loop with a new ObjectContext and end it with SaveChanges, which I think will affect performance. Also, could you tell me why ORCSolutionsDataService.tblSellerListings (An ADO.NET DataServices/WCF object is not IDisposable, like LINQ to Entities??

==============================================

```
// Add listings to previous seller
int NewSellerID = 0;

// Look up existing Seller key using SellerUniqueEBAYID
var qryCurrentSeller = from s in service.tblSellers
                       where s.SellerEBAYUserID == SellerUserID
                       select s;

foreach (var s in qryCurrentSeller)
    NewSellerID = s.SellerID;

// Save the selected listings for this seller

foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvRows)
{

    ORCSolutionsDataService.tblSellerListings NewSellerListing = new ORCSolutionsDataService.tblSellerListings();
    NewSellerListing.ItemID = dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemID"].Value.ToString();
    NewSellerListing.Title = dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemTitle"].Value.ToString();
    NewSellerListing.CurrentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemPrice"].Value);
    NewSellerListing.QuantitySold = Convert.ToInt32(dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemSold"].Value);
    NewSellerListing.EndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemEnds"].Value);
    NewSellerListing.CategoryName = dgr.Cells["txtSellerItemCategory"].Value.ToString();
    NewSellerListing.ExtendedPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dgr.Cells["txtExtendedReceipts"].Value);
    NewSellerListing.RetrievedDtime = Convert.ToDateTime(dtSellerDataRetrieved.ToString());
    NewSellerListing.SellerID = NewSellerID;

    service.AddTotblSellerListings(NewSellerListing);

}

service.SaveChanges();
```

}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to add a new case. Exception: " + ex.Message);

}

Comment: What is the primary key in NewSellerListing? BTW, you don't really need the first foreach loop to get the sellerId, you can put that in your query directly: NewSellerID = (from s in service.tblSellers where s.SellerEBAYUserID == SellerUserID select s.SellerID).First(); // Of course, you need to handle if no ID is found, but this save database time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you doing a foreach var s in qryCurrentSeller and constantly re-assigning the value to NewSellerID.  NewSellerID will only ever take the last iteration of the first foreach???

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new object based on the old values, specifying the ID, and saving it to the DB. If that is true, then the new object will have the same ID as the one it is copied from. Are you updating, or saving a new record?

It also looks like there might be a much faster way to accomplish the same thing. If you can get the list of IDs that are being reassigned or copied, you could use SQL similar to:

```
update tblSellerListings set SellerID = "new seller id" where ItemID in (list of ids);
```

Re-using the context may be an issue if it is keeping around the incrementing ID from query to the next. Creating a new one would clear that value. I bet, if this is the case, that there is a method that will also clear that value.

Jacob